# JAVA Swing - Having multiple pages and using buttons to go through them

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, user-input

I am trying to make a program that essentially allows the user to switch through different areas of content for the user. The content area is essentially a place where you can draw different shapes.

For example, when the user starts up the program, they are able to edit and do things to the content area that pops up. However, there is the menu with the buttons "New", "Previous", "Next", "Delete".

- When you click "New" you should be able to essentially create a new content area (not a new page).
- When you make multiple content areas, you should be able to click "Next" or "Previous" to essentially go through the different content areas as soon as you click the button.
- When you click "Delete" you should be able to delete the current content area you are at.
- Finally, you should be able to not be able to click "Next" when you are at the end of the content areas and same with "Previous" when you are at the start.

Also, there should not be a creation of multiple pages, but rather the content area is essentially changing only. So, the menu bar stays in the same place with the content only changing when clicking the button. In this case, the content area is a space where you can draw shapes and when you add a new content area it should be a blank space and you can draw new things. As you access the previous content space, you should be able to see the old drawings

The card layout option seems like an option, but how would I take into account for there being a large number of pages?

Any ideas of how to approach this?

Comment: *but I do not know how to convert such to support it in the GUI.* - Read the [Swing Tutoroal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. Then ask specific questions, not general questions, about what you don't understand. You question is way to vague to give a suggestion. Not only that, the last two times I gave suggestions with  with your dragging problem, you simply deleted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193636/able-to-move-a-shape-i-have-drawn-and-to-move-it-freely without taking the time to thank anybody for the help received.

Comment: Apologies for deleting the question. I am just struggling to understand a lot of it. My apologies again and thank you.

Comment: *but rather the content area is essentially changing only.* - so we have no idea what your content area is. So for example maybe you have a JTestArea display the content. Then when you click a button you invoke the setText(...) method to replace the old text with the new text.

Comment: Sorry about not being specific. In this case, the content area is a space where you can draw shapes and when you add a new content area it should be a blank space and you can draw new things. As you access the previous content space, you should be able to see the old drawings.

Comment: Then a CardLayout sounds reasonable. You can add unlimited panels and easily move through each panel. You can check out [CardLayout Actions](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/card-layout-actions/) which adds some functionality to the CardLayout to enable you to easily go to the Next/Previous card.

Comment: How would I take the consideration of maybe having an infinite number of adds?

Comment: Thanks for your help.